# WindowsApplication1.myprojectDataSet7TableAdapters.database_tableTableAdapter is not defined

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have transferred the VB.Net project .sln from VB 2008 version to VB 2010 version using Visual studio 2010 tool. After that when i open .sln file i am getting these type of errors. I am new for VB.Net Any suggestions would be appreciated

> Error 2 Type
>   'WindowsApplication1.myprojectDataSet7TableAdapters.database_tableTableAdapter
>   is not defined

Comment: Are you sure you have the complete code? Or do you see some broken references (you see it in solution eplorer, or some imports are wavy underlined)

Comment: Yes i have the complete code. No broken references or wavy underlines in the import but there is some wavy underline in the code

Comment: Me.Bible_engTableAdapter4.Fill(Me.projectDataSet7.database)

Comment: What are the wavy underlines tell you if you hover over them with the mouse? Try retargeting to a more recent framework (I would suppose the 2013 Community Edition of Visual Studio - it installs Framework 4.5.1.). Try "Clean Solution" and then "Rebuild Solution". Provide the erronous code part here.

Comment: Type 'WindowsApplication1.myprojectDataSet7TableAdapters.database_tableTableAdapter is not defined

Comment: I looks like you do NOT have all code. When you opened the project the first time with VS2010, what did the upgrade report tell you?

Comment: When i opened the project in VS 2010 for first time it took me to the  VS convertion wizard and after Finish this errors are coming

Comment: Again, I have to ask: What message got you from the conversion wizard? The "myprojectDataSet7TableAdapters" class/module: can you find this string somewhere in your solution (other place than where the error occurs)? Are there some "wavy´s"?

Comment: Convertion wizard in the end said it is converted successfully. But the report shows in the SOLUTION .sln is converted and .suo is not converted. In PROJECTS all are converted

Comment: In error list it is showing as many as 128 errors Error 1 Custom tool error: Failed to generate code. Failed to generate code. Exception of type 'System.Data.Design.InternalException' was thrown. Exception of type 'System.Data.Design.InternalException' was thrown

Comment: No i cannot find the string myprojectDataSet7TableAdapters anywhere in my solution explorer

Comment: Then you have ___NOT___ all of the code!