# How do I identify if a program is written using Visual Basic 6.0 or VB.NET...?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb6

I am not familiar with Visual Basic 6.0 or VB.NET. I got an old project from the client for modification. So I want to identify whether the code is written in Visual Basic 6.0 or VB.NET.

Any suggestion or any major syntax difference so that I can find it faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could check the project filesystem structure.

If the main project file has the extension **.Vbp** it means it is a Visual Basic 6.0 project, otherwise, if the main project file has the extension **.VBProj** file then it is an VB.NET project.

If you would like to determine the language based on a code analysis then there are several ways to determine it.

You could check for VB.NET-only statements like **[Option Strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**,  **[Option Inffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx)**, etc. In Visual Basic 6.0 there is only `Option Explicit`.

Any commonly used class from the **[.NET framework class library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** like `MessageBox` (not `MsgBox`).

Any **[Visual Basic Language Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)** that only appears in VB.NET like `Imports`, `Handles`, `Inherits`, etc. (note that some others are shared with Visual Basic 6.0).

The common event handler signature **[ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

The error-handling **[Try/Catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx)** block

```
Try
Catch
Finally
End Try
```

And much more. Refer to **[Visual Basic .NET Language Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712050%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**.

Comment: I have a file with .vbproj extension. But inside my setting file it is written as visual basic version 8.0.0.0 which really i didnt understand.

Comment: I have many files with .vb extension and my code looks like this        Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Comment: Public Class Form1
    Public Shared tb As RichTextBoxDim asts As String
    Public Sub New(ByVal strTextBox As String, ByVal stgs As String)
        InitializeComponent()
        If strTextBox <> "" Then
            TextBox2.Text = strTextBox
        End If
        If stgs <> "" Then
            asts = stgs
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: @Nathan: Visual Basic 8.0.0.0 - Visual Studio 2005 (.NET started with Visual Basic 7.0.0.0 in year 2002)

Comment: Thanks a lot ElektroStudios

Comment: I have one more question related to this @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601135/windowsapplication1-myprojectdataset7tableadapters-database-tabletableadapter-is

Comment: One sure way is by code Events:  `Handles ....` is VB.NET  as is AddHandler.

Comment: As an aside, the `AddressOf` keyword was also available in VB6

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
tasklist /m
```

Visual Basic 6.0 will have `MSvbvm60.dll` loaded and any .NET program will load `mscoree.dll`.

A program may load both though if one is using features of the other as is possible with objects. In this case the list of DLL files near the beginning of the EXE file will tell you - use Notepad.